# How to create a custom filter to filter by band name existence in Earthengine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm working with a Imagecollection that doesn't have the same band for it's 2018  and 2019 collection. It's enoying but bot the first time I encounter this situation. I would like to create a custom filter that remove images that don't have a specific band name.

For the sake of clarity I created a super small example here:

```py
image1 = ee.Image.constant(1).rename("first")
image2 = ee.Image.constant(2).rename("sencond")
ic = ee.ImageCollection([image1, image2])

# what I would like to do 
ic = ic.filter(mycustomfilter("first"))
```

I know that I could solve this very example with a simplee map function but the real problem lying under it (filter collection if multiple band are ALL or ANY present) is more complex to illustrate and will be solved with a combination of this more simple filter.

My main problem is that I know how to check properties, values but how to check band names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a custom filter.
You can access the band names using the system:band_names property which presents them as a list, and filter for ones you want using the `listContains` filter.

```
collection.filter(ee.Filter.listContains("system:band_names", "first"))
```